# JavaScript to to Call up and Send Parameters to JNLP file

Tags: javascript, java, jnlp

Has anyone been able to send parameters such as a variable to a JNLP file using Javascript?  I am trying to create a dynamic JNLP file, that the serverURL changes each time.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  A client side language like JS is not going to achieve this.  It requires writing on the server side by PHP, ASP, servlet etc.